# Magento 1.9 upgrade and paypal problem

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, paypal

Help, we have upgraded to Magento 1.9 and when customers use Paypal on there mobile or tablet the payment wont go through. It works fine on the desktop but not on mobile, please help, we are at a loss as we have had to disable the mobile site and don't want to get penalised by google for not being mobile friendly.

Comment: Do you have console errors when viewing say iphone in chrome developer?